# asp.net ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

My ERP web application written in c#.net throwing this error frequently

[image]

I have Globals.cs file under App_Code folder like:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;

public static class Globals
{
public static string mycon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebConnStr"].ConnectionString;
public static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
public static SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
public static SqlDataReader dr;

public static void Initialize(string CmdType, string CmdText)
{
    try
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        if (CmdType == "StoredProcedure")
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        }
        cmd.CommandText = CmdText;
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

}
}
```

my connection string in web.config looks like:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name=WebConnStr connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=username; Password=12345" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

my sample aspx.cs codes like:

Gridview Bind:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Globals.Initialize("StoredProcedure", "[sp_getemp]");
Globals.dr = Globals.cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(Globals.dr);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Insert Query:

```
Globals.Initialize("StoredProcedure", "[sp_insertemp]");
Globals.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", txtempid.Text);
Globals.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Data Reading:

```
private string GetEmpName(string empcode)
{
    Globals.Initialize("Text", "SELECT EmpName from tbl_emp where EmpID=@EmpID");
    Globals.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", empcode);
    Globals.dr = Globals.cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (Globals.dr.Read() == true)
    {
        return Globals.dr["EmpName"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

May I know what might have gone wrong in Globals.cs file and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is wrong is that your code is *absolutely terrible*. Please read up on connection pooling at least.

Comment: The error messages tells you that you need an open and available connection and the connection state is open. I guess that means that the connection is not available.

Comment: Please look at the link that provided. It's _almost_ the same thing that you faced. Don't stuck with `Open` and `Connecting` words..

Answer (score 1):

That is why you should be using the `using` statement to get rid of this type of error. Something like

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   //some code
}
```

You can refer this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) and read about connection pooling:

> In practice, most applications use only one or a few different
>   configurations for connections. This means that during application
>   execution, many identical connections will be repeatedly opened and
>   closed. To minimize the cost of opening connections, ADO.NET uses an
>   optimization technique called connection pooling.
>
> Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections
>   must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical
>   connection. It manages connections by keeping alive a set of active
>   connections for each given connection configuration. Whenever a user
>   calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available
>   connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it
>   returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When the
>   application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to
>   the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once the
>   connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the
>   next Open call.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to open a connection before executing code, and example being `conn.Open();`